# Why does my COM call fail when run on another thread?

Tags: c++, windows, com

I have some code that I want to run on a background thread.

```
bool CallThreadSafeInvokeCommand(std::unique_ptr<ShellInvokeCommandInfo> const pInvokeCommandInfo, CComPtr<IContextMenu> const pContextMenu)
{
    if (!pInvokeCommandInfo || !pContextMenu)
    {
        return false;
    }

    CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO* pici = *pInvokeCommandInfo;
    return SUCCEEDED(pContextMenu->InvokeCommand(pici));
}
```

The code always works when run on the main thread, but *sometimes* fails when run on a background thread.  It get's an E_FAILED from InvokeCommand().

My main thread is running as a single threaded COM apartment and I've called CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) on the background thread too.

I'm starting to wonder if my problem relates to the fact that the COM interface I'm using for the context menu was created on a different thread.  The rules here state:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/single-threaded-apartments

- Every object should live on only one thread (within a single-threaded apartment).
- Initialize the COM library for each thread.
- Marshal all pointers to objects when passing them between apartments.

So question:

How can I make my CComPtr properly accessible from the second thread?

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer, you need to use `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`:     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-comarshalinterthreadinterfaceinstream

Comment: Ah right yes, marshal to an IStream in one thread and then unmarshal in the other, got it, thanks!

Comment: @RichardCritten Hmm, that seems to fail because the IContextMenu I'm using doesn't have marshalling support.  I get a REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG (0x80040155) back from the call to CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream().

Comment: Yep. You're doomed: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090122-00/?p=19413 can't use IContextMenu in another thread